# Can I change the icon of a Windows Boot Entry?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bootloader, bcd

Is ist possible to change the icon for the ArchLinux entry shown below for Windows 10 (e.g. to the ArchLinux logo instead of the cmd-ish icon), using BCDEdit or some other tool?

[image: Windows Default Boot Entries Images]

Comment: There is surprisingly little to no information on this online. I suspect the answer might lie within the EFI file each boot entry directs to, but I have yet to successfully edit that to find it.

Comment: Ok, I managed to open those files with a resource viewer but none of them seemed to contain the icon. It might be somewhere else. Please update the post if you find it yourself.