# What are the relevant boot components (files and settings) of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot, debug

This is my second question regarding [my case of a non-booting Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1316693/can-i-see-what-happens-behind-the-windows-dell-in-that-case-boot-logo), but with a different focus this time. As a reminder:

> Since something(TM) happened with my laptop (Dell Latitude E6440) yesterday (I suspect a Windows Update, but who knows), my Windows 10 Pro installation (17134.1, if that matters) does not boot any longer. Basically, during bootup I saw only a Dell logo indefinitely, with nothing else happening beside some initial hard disk activity.

I have ruled out the Windows Boot Manager as a root cause, not least by installing the same version of Windows 10 on a second partition, managed by the same one EFI boot manager. [There seems to be no way to upgrade/in-place-install over an existing, non-booting Windows installation *and keep apps installed*, so this is not my preferred solution. I would like to repair the broken one.] The boot menu works fine with all configured options, it's just that I cannot boot one of the two Windows installations. Despite corresponding BCD configuration, a `%WINDIR%\Ntbtlog.txt` log file is not written, so I suspect that the boot sequence fails very early on (that is, even before `ntoskrnl.exe` is loaded.) I thought that maybe the Windows Boot *Loader* of that installation was broken.

So I started to look for differences between the respective files. I made sure the BCD looks the same except for additional logging and debugging options:

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {the-working-one}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {uid1}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
flightsigning           Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {uid2}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {non-working-one}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10-1
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {uid3}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
flightsigning           Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \Windows
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
bootstatuspolicy        DisplayAllFailures
bootlog                 Yes
sos                     Yes
```

Then I continued by comparing files that I suspect have something to do with booting - but everything that I have tested so far is identical, too:

```
C:\Windows\Boot\* == D:\Windows\Boot\* (recursive)
C:\Windows\System32\*boot*.* == D:\Windows\System32\*boot*.*
C:\Windows\System32\*bcd*.* == D:\Windows\System32\*bcd*.*
C:\Windows\System32\*winload*.* == D:\Windows\System32\*winload.*
C:\Windows\System32\Boot\* == D:\Windows\System32\Boot\* (recursive)
```

What am I missing? What are other relevant boot components of Windows 10 that I could compare? Is there another way to isolate the *relevant* differences between the two installations that might allow me to copy over part from the-working-one to the non-working-one?

Two additional pieces of information that might help point into the right direction:

1. During recovery with just the non-working Windows installation, "bootrec /fixboot" also exited with "Access denied", but I could not figure out which access was denied. I am not really eager to try this command out now, not knowing what it does exactly.
2. `D:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt` (the log file for start-up repair, run during Windows Recovery as well) contains this line;

> Boot critical file d:\efi\microsoft\boot\resources\custom\bootres.dll is corrupt.

I have no idea why a custom bootres.dll might be required, I don't have that anywhere. Where might this be registered? Interestingly, the only place I can find part of this error message are [these](https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update-insiderplat_pc/bug1713373-%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85%E5%A4%B1%E8%B4%A5/3add2b64-90b4-478b-b232-deb8100e19a9) [two](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/msftinsider/microsoft_lanza_una_acumulativa_para_los_usuarios_de_la_build_17133_en_insider/#comment-3849071135) threads, which relate to the 17133.73 (from 17133.1, I assume) update. I had indeed installed that update (successfully) after I had installed a clean 17133.1, but the subsequent clean update to 17134.1 went smoothly as far as I can tell. Still, I wonder whether this might indicate any left-overs from problems related to Microsoft pulling 17133 as an RTM build (e.g., in the EFI NVRAM).

3. The logos for the two entries in the Windows Boot Manager, when using the graphical versions, are different. So there must be a difference at the level of the Windows Boot Manager (or the Loaders) still:

[image]

I find it not too far off to hypothesize that the `custom\bootres.dll` issue above and the boot manager logo issue here are closely related. (Related question: [Can I change the icon of a Windows Boot Entry?](https://superuser.com/questions/1195986/)) What I don't get (yet) is why the Boot Manager thinks this entry needs custom resources at all.

Comment: If you suspect an update, then you should remove the update from within WinRE, a list of required boot files would likely be in the hundreds.  Windows 10 build 17134.1 is an Insider Preview build.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, I will try that. Still, I wonder - "in the hundreds" before `ntoskrnl.exe`?

Comment: "What are other relevant boot components of Windows 10 that I could compare?" - This list would be a very long list.  I was trying to polite and point you in the correct direction to solve this problem instead of saying, the list you want, won't be very helpful.

Comment: @Ramhoun I see :) I have run `dism /image=d: /get-packages` from my working Windows (targeting the non-working one) and while it shows the language packs,  OpenSSH, Media Player, etc. nothing seems to have been installed within a week of *the day*. The WindowsUpdate.log generated from events that day has things like the Photos app updated, but not hotfixes, KB or anything. So I guess Windows Update was not necessarily the culprit.

Comment: A change in a build 17133 to 17334 won’t show up in Windows Update.  Your issue is unrelated to the reason 17133 isn’t the RTM build of 1803.  Especially if you performed a clean install of 171334.

Answer (score -1):

buddy.

That's my first try to help people here, so don't kick me hard :)

I suggest you remove this "bootstatuspolicy        DisplayAllFailures" option row in a "non-working" boot record of yours.

You can handle this using "bcdedit /deletevalue {non-working-one} bootstatuspolicy" entered into cmd.exe , then reboot.

Have a nice day!